# How to use boost_threads with clang?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, boost-thread, clang++

I'm having trouble using boost_threads with clang. The clang version is 3.6.0 and boost version is 1.55.0 from the new Ubuntu 15.04. Program that used to work with previous versions of clang now segfaults at startup. There is no problems when I use g++ instead.

Here is an example program to illustrate the point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

void output() {
  try {
    int x = 0;
    for (;;) {
      boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
      cerr << x++ << endl;
    }
  } catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {}
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  try {
    boost::thread output_worker(output);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    output_worker.interrupt();
    output_worker.join();
  } catch (...) {
    cerr << "Unexpected error!" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

If I compile it with g++ it works, i.e.

```
g++ thread.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system
```

If I compile it with clang

```
clang++ thread.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system
```

I get a segfault with the gdb trace below

```
Starting program: /home/dejan/test/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd0580 in boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bd0580 in boost::exception_ptr boost::exception_detail::get_static_exception_object<boost::exception_detail::bad_alloc_>() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
#1  0x00007ffff7bcb16a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
#2  0x00007ffff7de95ba in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdf98, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdfa8)
   at dl-init.c:72
#3  0x00007ffff7de96cb in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#4  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe188, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf98, env=0x7fffffffdfa8) at dl-init.c:120
#5  0x00007ffff7dd9d0a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffe2fe in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's possible that there is a compatibility issue between clang 3.6 and boost 1.55. According to the boost release notes for 1.55, it was tested with clang versions up to 3.3. I tried your code with clang 3.6 and boost 1.58 on OSX and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Why not usw -std=c++11 and std::thread? Most likely You could just go and rename boost with std in this case

Comment: @Ferruccio: More likely an incompatibility between `g++` and `clang++` as the packages in Ubuntu are usually compiled with `gcc`/`g++`.

Comment: Try adding `-pthread` option.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling using `clang -std=c++11` makes boost change its internal implementation and actually solves the segmentation fault.
It is not an ideal solution, but it is the way I will be going with our code.